# tableview to another - IOS

Tags: ios, tableview

lets say i'm making an app where you add car manufacturers to the main viewcontroller thats a `UITableView`,
on the 2nd view controller (thats also a `UITableView`), you can add models of car under that manufacturers name.

now my problem is very simple, I can add manufacturers but when I presss on any manufacturers name I get the 2nd tableview with ALL of the models of all the manufacturers.

I tried using maybe predicates, filtering the mutablearray then passing it on to the 2nd view controller. no success :(

```
 NSPredicate * pred = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"currentCategoryOfImage = '%@'",[self.categoriesArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
    [self.myImagesObjArray filterUsingPredicate:pred];
    self.detailViewController.imagesItem = self.myImagesObjArray;
```

but i think theres somewhere a much simpler way to do this that still eludes me.

Comment: Can you tell us what went wrong beyond "no success"? Because the straightforward answer to your problem is to filter the data that's displayed in the second table according to what was chosen in the first table.

Answer (score 1):

You must not enclose `%@` in single quotes in the predicate:

```
NSPredicate *pred = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"currentCategoryOfImage = %@",[self.categoriesArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
```

And you probably don't want to modify `self.myImagesObjArray`, but set 
the detail view controllers list to the filtered array:

```
self.detailViewController.imagesItem = [self.myImagesObjArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:pred];
```

Comment: Incompatible pointer types assigning to 'NSMutableArray *' from 'NSArray *' when I try that, though its only a warning, still my filter doesnt filter right and I get all of the objectsarray instead of the specific one I want

Comment: If `self.detailViewController.imagesItem` is a NSMutableArray then `self.detailViewController.imagesItem = [[self.myImagesObjArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:pred] mutableCopy]` should work. But do you really need a mutable array? You should consider to declare `imagesItem` as `NSArray *`.

Comment: @EdenV.: Does it work now? Please let me know if you need more information.

Answer (score 0):

And if you don't like the first kind of predicate there is the predicate with block, something like this:

```
YourCustomObject = [self.categoriesArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
NSArray *resultArray = [yourArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate: [NSPredicate predicateWithBlock:^BOOL(YourCustomObject *object, NSDictionary *bindings) {
   return [YourCustomObject.comparedProperty isEqualTo:object.comparedProperty];
}]];
```

I didn't know your model classes names so I improvised.